# Creating two new datasets (CSV files) through R Studio based on Variables

Tags: r

I currently have a column called "Status" within my DF (Application) with binary values. I need to create two new CSV files through R studio with each containing only one of the binary values. I'm not sure how to do this.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with "only one"? In one csv only the "0"s and in the other only the "1"s? Is it just the column or are there any other columns supposed to go into the new csvs?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
application <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4), status = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE))

file1 <- application[application$status, ]
file2 <- application[! application$status, ]

write.csv(file1, "path/to/file1")
write.csv(file2, "path/to/file2")
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering your DF is called df, using `data.table`

```
df<-as.data.table(df)
df_0<-df[status == 0]
df_1<-df[status == 1]

write.csv(x = df_0,file = "status_0.csv",col.names = T)
write.csv(x = df_1,file = "status_1.csv",col.names = T)
```

Hope that helps.